# How to implement the two-person signature function on DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

To implement the two-person signature function, is there any other method besides saving the first person's signature as a template? For example: SetDocumentVisibilityService, I use Java, the error is as follows: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS","message ":"This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Document Visibility has been specified. This account does not have document visibility turned on."}'

Use SetDocumentVisibilityService to implement multi-person signature

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by two-person signature function? Are you just trying to request signature from two recipients? The error is related to Document Visibility which is a [different feature](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=eui1578456411411.html&_LANG=enus&language=en_US&rsc_301).

If you are trying to get signatures from two recipients, the [example](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/) in the API documentation should help. You'd need to add another signer object to the signers array similar to how the first signer is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error:

```
{"errorCode":"ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS","message ":"This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Document Visibility has been specified. This account does not have document visibility turned on."}
```

Log in to the DocuSign Web app, click **Settings** from the top-nav to go to the Admin area (administrators only, assume you have that permission) and then click on the left-nav **Sending Settings** where you will see a drop-down related to Document Visibility. I assume it's "Off" like in this screenshot. You need to change it to fix this.

I suggest you set it to:

[image]

[image]